# Compile-time error: expected constructor, destructor or conversion

Tags: c++, xcode

I need some help

does this piece of code look right ?

```
#include "programass.h"

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Student.h"
using namespace std;

template<class emptyValue>

struct DoublyLinkedNode
{
    emptyValue data;
    DoublyLinkedNode *prev, *next;
};
typedef DoublyLinkedNode<int> numListNode;
DoublyLinkedNode *listHead = NULL;
DoublyLinkedNode *listTail = NULL;
```

I keep getting a " expected constructor, destructor or conversion before "*" " error in debugger ? on the last two lines what have i done wrong ? :(

Answer (score 3):

You did

```
typedef DoublyLinkedNode<int> numListNode;
```

but in the next two lines

```
DoublyLinkedNode *listHead = NULL;
DoublyLinkedNode *listTail = NULL;
```

you forgot to use that new `numListNode` type. Change them to

```
numListNode *listHead = NULL;
numListNode *listTail = NULL;
```

Because you can't use a template class without a template argument, and you tried to do `DoublyLinkedNode *listHead` when it should have been `DoublyLinkedNode<something> *listHead`. So if you use your `typedef` which specifies the template argument (as `int`), it works.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you wanted to use numListNode instead of DoublyLinkedNode at the declaration of the two pointers.

```
numListNode* listHead = NULL;
numListNode* listTail = NULL;
```

On a side note I recommend removing the blank line between `template <class emptyValue>` and `struct DoublyLinkedNode`, and using the style `Type* ptr;` instead of `Type *ptr;`, it's nicer that way.

Comment: `type* ptr` vs `type *ptr` vs `type * ptr` has NO good answer -- several schools teach different, so it's not good advice. The school that sais `type *ptr` is driven by the fact that you wont make the mistake of typing `type* a, b;` and expect `a` and `b` to be pointers.

Comment: @Kornel Just so you know, [`type* ptr` is more C++'ish than `type *ptr` according to Stroustrup, and he prefers `type* ptr`](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#whitespace) :)

Comment: Well, I consider * being part of the type, it makes code much more transparent. My friend (who codes mainly in Java) agrees. And I don't particularly like comma separated declarations, I try not to use them.

Comment: @Seth, and so do I, but I know many fanatics who would fight otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Seth is right, but if I understand correctly, you're trying to build a generic data type, and hence want to have list head and tail also templated. For that you need a container struct that will also hold them:

```
template < typename emptyValue >
struct List 
{
    struct DoublyLinkedNode
    {
        emptyValue data;
        DoublyLinkedNode *prev, *next;
    };
    DoublyLinkedNode *head;
    DoublyLinkedNode *tail;

    ....
}

typedef List<int> numList;
```